# NSInternalInconsistencyException throwing by AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to open a storyboard from my AppDelegate but it throws me the exception:

```
2016-10-25 10:26:16.776 momnt[22865:1300106] *** Terminating app due to  
 uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
 reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view 
 controller at the end of application launch'
```

Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIStoryboard *loginStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *mainViewController = [loginStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I've read that newer versions of XCode requires that all the Windows must have a rootViewController but i've did that.

Comment: this means your app doesn't have any root vc to startup.

Comment: What is your project storyboard name?

Comment: @RonakChaniyara the file name is Login.storyboard. If i use another name, i got an error that doesn't found the storyboard.

Comment: Have you set any viewController to initial viewController in your `Login.storyboard`?

Comment: It was missing to check "Initial View Controller" on attributes inspector. Is possible to set it programmatically?

Comment: If you give the controller a storyboard ID, you can load it by that instead of calling `instantiateInitialViewController`.  ...but, if it's always going to be the same one, why bother?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug the application and check if `mainViewController` is not `nil`.

Problem seems that you don't have any viewController set as initial viewcontroller in your storyBoard.

Set any viewcontroller you want to initial viewcontroller and your code work fine.

***OR***

Use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` and pass your viewController identifier to which you want as initial viewController.

```
UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *mainViewController = [storybord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InitialViewControllerID"];

self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```